# JobRepositoryFactoryBean error spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I started to learn spring batch and I have a problem that when i want to
persist the state of the job in a database using `JobRepositoryFactoryBean`. 
compiler displays :

"**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [springConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedRowMapper**"

but not error when i use `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`

I'm using spring 5

springconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="springbatch" />
    <context:annotation-config />



    <bean id="personneReaderCSV" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="input/personnes.txt" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                        <property name="names" value="id,nom,prenom,civilite" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="targetType" value="springbatch.entities.Personne" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean name="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>springbatch.entities.Personne</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <job id="importPersonnes" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="readWritePersonne">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="personneReaderCSV" 
                processor="personProcessor"
                    writer="personWriter" 
                    commit-interval="2" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>

    <bean id="daoPersonne" class="springbatch.dao.PersonneDaoImp">
        <property name="factory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="personWriter" class="springbatch.batch.PersonneWriter">
            <property name="dao" ref="daoPersonne"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="personProcessor" class="springbatch.batch.PersonneProcess">
    </bean>

    <bean id="batchLauncher" class="springbatch.MyBean">
    </bean>


    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="Mysql" />

    </bean>


    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="batchLauncher" method="message"
            cron=" 59 * * * * * " />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>


</beans>
```

but not error when i use :

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" /> 
</bean>
```

Comment: I think the datasource should be a database connection details rather than the scripts which you have mentioned. Try giving the BasicDataSource bean for datasource.

Comment: i never heard about BasicDataSource can you help me to do that ?

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${Server}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${Username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${Password}"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="5"/>
    </bean>

Comment: Which version of Spring Batch are you using? Looks like `ParameterizedRowMapper` is not in the `spring-jdbc` jar you have in your classpath. Can you share your `pom.xml` or `gradle.build` to see your dependencies?

Comment: my dependencies : http://www4.0zz0.com/2018/12/14/22/202421158.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Spring Batch v2.2 with Spring Framework 5. That's not going to work properly as `ParameterizedRowMapper` has been removed in Spring Framework 4.2+ (hence the exception).

I recommend that you use Spring Batch v4.1 (since v2.x is not maintained anymore) and your issue should be fixed.

The best way to manage Spring dependencies is to let Spring Boot do it for you either by generating a project from [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io) or by using the [Spring Boot BOM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent). With both ways, you will have the correct Spring projects dependencies that are known to work well together.

Comment: after updating the spring batch to the v4  the problem is fixed thanks a lot !